# Insert annotation in PDF

Tags: vba, excel, pdf, annotations

I am looking for solution for interface between Excel+VBA and PDF. I am using VBA to insert an annotation in a PDF file.

As of now I am able to create the Freetext Box and add the text. But I have failed to use desired font type, font colour and font size.

Here is the complete code.

```
Function text_annotation(FileName, path, Proj_No, Dept_no, New_tag, sizex, sizey)

Dim pdDoc As Acrobat.CAcroPDDoc 
Dim page As Acrobat.CAcroPDPage

Dim jso As Object 
Dim point(2) As Integer
Dim popupRect(3) As Integer
Dim rect(3) As Integer
Dim pageRect As Object
Dim annot As Object
Dim props As Object
Dim text As Object

Set pdDoc = Nothing
Set app = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
Set pdDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")

fullpath = path & FileName
pdDoc.Open (fullpath)

Set jso = pdDoc.GetJSObject
If Not jso Is Nothing Then

Set page = pdDoc.AcquirePage(0)

Set pageRect = page.GetSize

Set annot = jso.AddAnnot

Set props = annot.getprops
    props.page = 0
    props.Name = "Entry_Stamp"
    props.Type = "FreeText"
    props.rect = popupRect
    props.Author = "user"
    props.Width = 1#
    props.strokeColor = jso.color.blue
    props.contents = "text mesg"

annot.setProps props
```

*These following line doesnot result properly.*

```
Set props = annot.getprops
With props
    'props.text = jso.color.blue
    'props.Fontcolor = jso.color.black
    'props.textFont = Font.Helv
    'props.textSize = 24

End With

annot.setProps props

End Function
```

I hope to use the VB script so that I can use my Excel template as well as do the annotation. Please suggest me the correction in the above code.

Comment: In your second code box, between "With" and "End With" you should remove "props" from the start of each line, or remove the "With" and "End With".

Comment: Hello Jongwarethank you

Comment: Dear Jongware, Thank you for your Response. I set the mistake right. But after that also there is amix Response.     **props.textSize = 24 (executes but no Change)
    'props.textcolor = jso.color.red (doesnot execute)
    props.textFont = "Font.Helv" (execute, but no Change)     props.textFont = Font.Helv (doesnot execute)** Basically I have tried all These combinations. As far as I have referred different web help and API documentation, These are correct. Somewhere I have gone wrong, hence I prefered to put the whole code. Please help.